# How to integrate webhook in website using php, html and ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, webhooks, webapi

I am integrating dunzo delivery in my website. They had given me an api. I have created tasks and tested and all is well. But I have confusion about webhook. I have idea about webhook that how it works. but don't know how to implement it in website.
I wanna get up to date info about delivery in my webpage without refreshing or reloading. it's something like notification. As I heard webhook is best for this but I don't know to integrate it.
Can someone help out?

Comment: Please send a selfy with hook you want so, some can write for you

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We can not help you out here, as long as you don’t describe a specific problem.

Comment: Can someone give example of full webhook implementation/integration in php?